# How is the first instruction of VirtualMachine is fetched (in KVM-QEMU)

Tags: x86, virtualization

I am new both to SO and X86 VMX.
I am learning KVM-QEMU on X86, and i want to know the details about how is the first instruction of the VM is fetched, so that the VM can start running.
There are KVM APIs to configure and register a set of memory as the physical memory for the VM, then, set the guest_RIP to AAA (for example).
I don't know when VMLaunch is called (with proper configured VMCS), how does the CPU could fetch the instruction from that RIP in VMCS, is it through some address translation process, so the guest_CR3 shall be set properly to point to the HOST memory allocated for the guest?
Thanks

Comment: Is this question so stupid or the answer is very straightforward, that no one wants to answer it?

Comment: Hi @wangt13, are you still looking for an answer towards this question ? If so, I can try explaining it in terms of QEMU and how QEMU with KVM tries to do this activity.

Comment: @Arnabjyoti, I would be very appreciated if you can share your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will explain this in the context of QEMU and how QEMU operates when the KVM accelerator is enabled.

As you might be knowing, under kvm, virtual machines are created by opening a device node `/dev/kvm`. A guest will have its own memory and is usually separate from the userspace process that created it. So basically kvm is structured as a fairly typical Linux character device - you use `ioctl()`s to create, run, modify parameters, allocate memory and read and write to the VCPU registers of the virtual machines. Thus, the initial setup will be done via various `ioctl()`s that will setup KVM for further use.

In terms of the QEMU code, all execution(whether KVM or non-KVM) starts from :

[vl.c start of everything](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/vl.c#L3091)

The initialization of the KVM architecture happens via the below function -- (collecting CPU flags from **CPUID** and setting up frequencies etc.)

[kvm_arch_init_vcpu](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/7ec6a364916c0d1eba01128481e503a550a2b466/target/i386/kvm.c#L693)

Once all the initialization functions are done, the function `do_kvm_cpu_synchronize_post_init` will try to synchronize the initial values of the VCPU registers based on the host CPU state. It calls another function, 
`kvm_arch_put_registers` and sets the VCPU to be **dirty**. Why is the VCPU set to dirty ? Only then will the subsequent functions actually initialize the values of the VCPU registers.

This function `kvm_arch_put_registers` is the key to obtaining all the initial values of the VMCS registers. If you see its body, you will realize what is happening :-

[kvm_arch_put_registers](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/7ec6a364916c0d1eba01128481e503a550a2b466/target/i386/kvm.c#L2593)

Specifically focus on the functions, `kvm_getput_regs` and `kvm_put_sregs` - the first function will set up the initial values of the **GPRs** and the **EFLAGS** as well as the **EIP/RIP** register, while the second function will set up the initial segment register values.

The **guest page table** will be rooted to the **CR3** register. How does this page table work ?

For this, you need to remember that the **mmu** in KVM only accounts for one level of virtualization ( guest virtual -> guest physical ) but does not account for the second level ( guest physical -> host physical ). The initial RIP will account for virtual addresses - it will be appropriately translated to physical addresses in the guest. However, to convert this guest physical address to the host physical address, you need to have a separate page table. This is a **shadow page table** that will be used in conjunction with the **original page table** (that converts guest virtual -> guest physical) to perform the entire translation.

There is a need for **synchronizing** the state of the **guest page table** with the **shadow page table** and this sometimes tends to be a problem. Whenever the guest will write to its page table, the corresponding changes need to be performed on the shadow page tables as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer.
Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.
To start the VM (first instruction, normally in real mode), KVM needs to setup VM memory, put the bootup code into the memory for VM, then setup the EIP/RIP to the address of the first instruction, and call vmlaunch at last to start the VM.

Comment: @Wangt13, yes, from the high level, you are right. But there are a lot more things that happen in the middle.